# Remove all handlers from a boost::asio::io_service without calling them

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I want to remove all handlers from an IO_service right before I reuse it.  Is this possible?

I'm writing unit tests that involve an `asio::io_service`.  In between each test case I want to clear the handlers from the global `io_service`.  I thought that `io_service::reset` would to that but it doesn't.  `reset()` only allows the `io_service` to be resumed.  All of the handlers from the last test case are still queued up.

I only need to do this for unit testing so any crazy hack would work.

---

More info:

The `io_service` is from a `deadline_timer` member variable.  The `deadline_timer` is part of the code I'm testing so I can't change how it's constructed.  I get a hold of its `io_service` via the `deadline_timer`'s `get_io_service` method.

Comment: You can't create an `io_service` in your `setup()` method and then destroy it in your `teardown()` method, can you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I racked my brain on this for a few days and came up with a workable solution.  It's the mother of all hacks.

```
void clear( boost::asio::io_service& service )
{
    service.stop();
    service.~io_service();
    new( &service ) boost::asio::io_service;
}
```

I'm not sure how safe this would be for productions code.  But so far it seems to work (no segfaults, no weird behavior).

Comment: You could allocate the io_service dynamically and store it in an std::auto_ptr or boost::scoped_ptr.  Then you can reset it when you need to "clear" the handlers.  That way you avoid using placement new (in which case you need to explicitly call the destructor - see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10).

Comment: @Yukiko: I don't control the code that creates the io_service.  Further I don't contol the code that sets the deadline_timer's io_service.  In short I don't allocate the io_service so I can't store it in smart_ptr.

Comment: I am using boost 1.49. That trick is not working (some assertion failed)